# Issue with number-formatting

Tags: javascript, html, phone-number, libphonenumber

I'd like to format a phoneNumber like `2133734253` with a given country code (like `"US"`) to national format using the [libphonenumber library](https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js).

What I've found in the docs is something like:

[image]

---

Because I'm not using `node.js` or something else I'm just linking the js-file from https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js/bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js.

Using the `new libphonenumber.formatNumber()`-call does not seems to work because it is return a object with absolutely no content **every time**. How can I fix this? How to use `formatNumber()` the right way?

```js
let phonenumber = new libphonenumber.formatNumber({ 
                                      country: 'US', 
                                      phone: '2133734253' 
                                    }, 'National');
console.log(phonenumber) // should be (213) 373-4253
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js/bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, libphonenumber is not a constructor, it just provides functions, hence remove the `new` keyword :

```js
let phonenumber = libphonenumber.formatNumber({ 
                                      country: 'US', 
                                      phone: '2133734253' 
                                    }, 'National');
console.log(phonenumber) // should be (213) 373-4253
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js/bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is drop the `new`. It is not needed here, it is a utils library and does not need to be instantiated:

```js
let phonenumber = libphonenumber.formatNumber({ 
                                      country: 'US', 
                                      phone: '2133734253' 
                                    }, 'National');
console.log(phonenumber) // should be (213) 373-4253
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/libphonenumber-js/bundle/libphonenumber-js.min.js"></script>
```